# How to echo a PHP variable from MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, json, variables, select

To automate my PHP to generate JSON, I saved the name of variable in database 
(e.g. > `$test_value_1`).

In my php file I have the value of this variable (e.g. > `$test_value_1 = "TEST VALUE 1"`)

After this I do a query to echo this variable, but, instead of returning the value of variable (TEST VALUE 1), always return just the text save in database ("$teste_value_1")

To understand better, look my database, variable, query, response and what I need:

**TABLE: attributes**

```
   id_attribute |  attribue_string | attribute_value
    1            |  test_string_1  | $test_value_1
    2            |  test_string_2  | $test_value_2
```

**VARIABLES:**

```
$test_value_1 = "Test Value 1"; 
$test_value_2 = "Teste Value 2";
```

**QUERY:**

```
$query_array = mysqli_query($connect,"
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{id:', a.attribute_string, ',value_name:', a.attribute_value, '}') SEPARATOR ', ') AS concat
    FROM rel_categories_attributes AS rca
    INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id_category = rca.categories_id_category
    INNER JOIN attributes AS a ON a.id_attribute = rca.attributes_id_attribute
    WHERE id_category = '{$id_category}'
    ");
WHILE ($reg_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($query_array)){

    echo $teste_query = $reg_cat["concat"] . ",";
```

**RESPONSE:** `{id:test_string_1,value_name:$test_value_1}, {id:teste_string_2,value_name:$test_value_2}`, (WRONG)

**WHAT I NEED:** `{id:test_string_1,value_name:TEST VALUE 1}, {id:teste_string_2,value_name:TESTE VALUE 2}`,

Comment: What's wrong with `json_encode()`?

Comment: why for the love of Buddha are you storing php variable names in a db?

Comment: @nogad hehehe because I have a lot of differents products with differents attributes with differents values names, so, i think this is the best away to get all informations automatically

Comment: Why don't you have a table in the database with the values, and then join with that?

Comment: really its not, its never is, there are better ways to do this

Comment: @Xorifelse I use json_encode() to encode the response of variable, but, doesn't work for me in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this seems like a horrible design, you can do it using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). But you'll need to do the output formatting in PHP, not in MySQL.

```
$query_array = mysqli_query($connect,"
    SELECT a.attribute_string, a.attribute_value
    FROM rel_categories_attributes AS rca
    INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id_category = rca.categories_id_category
    INNER JOIN attributes AS a ON a.id_attribute = rca.attributes_id_attribute
    WHERE id_category = '{$id_category}'
");

$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_array) {
    $result[] = array('id' => $row['attribute_string'], 'value_name' => ${$row['attribute_value']});
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

However, variable variables can almost always be improved by using an associative array. Instead of having variables like `$test_value_1` and `$test_value_2`, create an array whose keys are `"test_value_1"` and `"test_value_2"`, and then use `$array[$row['attribute_value']]`.

But even better would be to put all the details in the database itself, rather than hard-coding them in the scripts. You can then join with that table to translate the attribute value to the appropriate string.

Comment: This solution work perfectly to me! By the way we really had a special reason to have variable listed in database.